# Repeating program in C#

Tags: c#

I have created a dice simulator program in C# but in the assignment requirements it says it needs to be able to repeat as many times as the user wants.

It's simple in python:

```
def var():

    import random

    dicesides = int(input("Please enter the amount of sides you want the dice that is being thrown to have. The dice sides available are: 4, 6 and 12: "))
    script(dicesides, random)

def script(dicesides, random):  
    if dicesides in (4,6,12):
        dice = int(random.randrange(1, dicesides))
        print(dicesides, " sided dice, score", dice)
    else:
        print("That number is invalid. Please try again.")
        var()

    repeat = str(input("Repeat? Simply put yes or no : "))

    if repeat == "yes":
        var()
    else:
        quit()            
var()
```

And this is my c# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            int num;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of sides you want the dice that is being thrown to have. The dice sides available are: 4, 6 and 12: ");
            num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (num == 4 || num == 6 || num == 12)
            {
                int randomDice = random.Next(0, num);
                Console.WriteLine(num + " sided dice thrown, " + randomDice);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That number is invalid. Please try again.")
            }


        }
```

How would I get the program to repeat?

Comment: Obviously you need a loop

Comment: By the way, your call to `random.Next()` should use `1` as a lower bound and `num + 1` as an exclusive upper bound, unless you're simulating a D6 that goes from 0 to 5, e.g.

Comment: @DStanley: It's still accomplishing the same thing: repeating the process until an exit condition is met. That's a loop, regardless of how it's done. The similarity to me is very apparent, and I've never written a single line of Python code. "repeat..until" or "while this condition exists do" is pretty clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a `while(true)` with a `break`:

```
    Random random = new Random();
    while(true)
    {
        int num;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of sides you want the dice that is being thrown to have. The dice sides available are: 4, 6 and 12: ");
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (num == 4 || num == 6 || num == 12)
        {
            int randomDice = random.Next(0, num);
            Console.WriteLine(num + " sided dice thrown, " + randomDice);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That number is invalid. Please try again.")
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Try again? (yes/no)");
        if(Console.ReadLine().ToLower() != "yes")
             break;   // end the while loop
    }
```

Note that a cleaner method would be to put  the guts of the loop in a separate function and call that from the loop:

```
static Random random = new Random();   // make the Random a field of the class for reuse
public static void Main()
    while(true)
    {
        RollDie();
        Console.WriteLine("Try again? (yes/no)");
        if(Console.ReadLine().ToLower() != "yes")
             break;   // end the while loop
    }
}
public static void RollDie()
{
    int num;
    while(true)
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of sides you want the dice that is being thrown to have. The dice sides available are: 4, 6 and 12: ");
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (num == 4 || num == 6 || num == 12)
        {
            int randomDice = random.Next(0, num);
            Console.WriteLine(num + " sided dice thrown, " + randomDice);
            break; // exit the while loop
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That number is invalid. Please try again.")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to put your code in a while loop, like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to roll the dice ? Y/N");
        char c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        while(c.ToLower() == 'y')
        {
        Random random = new Random();

        int num;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of sides you want the dice that is being thrown to have. The dice sides available are: 4, 6 and 12: ");
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (num == 4 || num == 6 || num == 12)
        {
            int randomDice = random.Next(0, num);
            Console.WriteLine(num + " sided dice thrown, " + randomDice);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That number is invalid. Please try again.")
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to roll it again? Y/N");
        c = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
      }

    }
```

Hope it helps...